# determining the format in which date is coming in excel through poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

Please advise one thing from excel i am reading cells data in which there are few cells in which dates are coming , now lets say one cell in which date is there is of date data type as i check by clicking on that cell and checking its data type but the other cell in which date is there are of string and text type .

now the dates in cell can be of UK format or of US format also so is there any way lets say if dates are coming as string in cell in excel we can check the format in which date is coming through POI in java and then can take necessary actions

so my major concern is for string cells in which date is coming as i want to determine that if date is coming and is of which format as i have to so some logic based on the for mats of the date

i am using poi 3.5 in java 5 to read the excel data

Comment: Apache POI will happily let you read "proper" date cells as a Java date object. Storing dates (or any number really) as a string cell rather than a date/numeric cell is generally advised against, is there a reason why you're doing that in your spreadsheet to start with?

Comment: Well actly most of the cells are of Date type and few are of numeric type also but since we are receiving this as from upstream so for few cells they are sending date as of string type that's why,  anyways is there any way to overcome from this

Comment: Ask the user where in the world they're from, and base it on that. Or make them use ISO-8601 format for all dates, as that's non-ambiguous. Your problem otherwise is not a coding problem, it's a bug in the real world...

Comment: Thanks I will ask the user to send the dates in date data type cell they are free to send date in cell I  any format but they should sent it in date type cell and then poi us intelligent enough to determine the format and return the java date object,  please correct me if I am wrong here

Comment: If it's date formatted, POI can give you the date. If it's random text in a string cell, in a random format, then all you can do is guess!

Comment: Yeah got the point, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Proper way is, that you will specify that it has to be in date format, if not reject the input from user.

You cannot find whether 2/3/2015 is US (February) or UK (March) date...

You can do some best effort approach, but you will have problems with this...

Comment: Yeah agree with you completely on this as I think java poi is not intelligent enough

Comment: It's not about the poi, those two formats have "collisions" - dates you do not know in which format they are in as shown above.